# Age is undefined in oxford project

Tags: javascript

so I'm getting an error of age is undefined. this is the project oxford code. My API key is updated.

```
var oxford = require('project-oxford');
client2 = new oxford.Client(//my api key);

client2.face.detect({
    path: '../practiceCode/cropped.jpeg',
    analyzesAge: true,
    analyzesGender: true
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log('The age is: ' + response[0].attributes.age);
    console.log('The gender is: ' + response[0].attributes.gender);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: do `console.log(response[0].attributes)` inside `.then()` and you will have an answer.

Comment: adding to @Ibu's comment, see if the `console.log` output contains data for age

Comment: Even better, `console.log(response)` - response might not be an array

Comment: i did that and it still shows its undefined, so i suppose i still have the same issue  "The age is: undefined"

Comment: if i do console.log(response) i get "the age is: [object Object]" if i do console.log(response[0].attributes) i get "the age is: undefined

Comment: no no, don't do `console.log('The age is: ' + response[0].attributes);` do it on it's own separate line. The whole point is to print the object you are returning and see what it contains. so do `console.log(response)` on its own, as suggested by others.

Comment: yup i got it i should have typed response[0].faceAttributes.age